# Android studio..NavigationView

Tags: android, image, drawable, navigationview

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\Android\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
**now it is showing this too--**
AAPT err(Facade for 1222374806): C:\Users\Rajinder\Desktop\FloatingLabels\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\logo.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

This error comes when I add images for `NavigationView` for all dpi in drawable folders.

Comment: it may be a problem with image name

Comment: images name starts with nav_address, nav_signout etc.sss

Comment: all letters are small.

Comment: images are .png format

Comment: try clean and rebuild

Comment: 1) i tried clean & build ..
2) File > Invalidate caches/Restart. also

any other option would be appreciated..

Comment: Maybe you need to install some 32-bit dependencies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio

Comment: chack also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645961/android-studio-processdebugresources-failed

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402048/android-studio-error-code-1-gradle-execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdeb

Comment: last one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485209/aapt-error-138-processdebugresources

Comment: not working...@piotrek1543

Comment: What is images for NavigationView? where did you use them?

Comment: i used them in activity.xml for left navigation ..and menu.xml defined in menu folder with title and drawable (for all dpi).

Answer (score 0):

add following line in

line:`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

`<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`

Use Lib  version

`dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}`